# how to pass the form data to confirmation then to result page

Tags: symfony

I am planning to make input form,structures are like this below.

input page -> comfirmation page -> resultpage

1)input page

user input data ex)

```
$userData = new UserData();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($userData)
->add('name','string')
->add('note','text')
->add('time,'date time')
->getForm();
```

2)confirmation page

show contents of post data

```
$request = $this->get('request');
$form->bindRequest($request);
```

in twig

```
<div>
Note : {{form.note.vars.varle}}
</div>
```

and

ask user like 'please confirm?'

3)result page

show 'thanks very much '

and then input all data to the database.

it is easy to bring data 1) -> 2)

If I need to put the data to database here,there is no problem.

However I have to show confirmation page and then go page 3)

How can I pass the post data from 2) to 3)?

I should put every data like this?It might be dangerous I think.

```
<input type=hidden name='name' value='test name'>
<input type=hidden name='note' value='this is note'>
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much more verbose answer, hopefully this helps and I didn't miss anything.  Let me know if I need to comment on anything.

Update:

Built a Symfony project with the views and everything.  Should make it much easier to understand.

https://github.com/KHannel/stackOverflowQ17623903

Comment: Thanks @Ken Hannei,I might not understand though,,,I can get data and show in comfirmation page ,but I want to pass the whole post data to result page for inputting in database.I edited article.

Comment: Made the answer much more verbose, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @Ken Hannei,I am not sure yet why postdata in showFormAction    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) { ... } could pass to resulPageAction...

Comment: Built out a Symfony project for you, hope this helps. - https://github.com/KHannel/stackOverflowQ17623903

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's great experience for me. I will study by this. I really appreciate your kindness